# Last Activity Date - Better Ideas for implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, android-activity

For a typical user registration and membership system i follow in ASP.NET website i would like to update the last activity date and time. Which of the below methods would be ideal to follow.

#### 1

Whenever a request is made to a method that access the data from the user account table, automagically(O_o)  update the `last_account_activity` date using `GETDATE()`

#### 2

Call `UpdateLastActivity()` as a method external after a method is called from the membership system.

info:

In terms of reliability the #2 is ideal because i can't rely in #1 when user actively using data from other tables rather than user account table.

What do you think? U got another way for me to do it?

#### Specs

.NET Framework 2.0

Asp.net 2.0

Custom Membership Provider Implementation

Sql Server 2005 Database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach 2 is better than 1.

**Suggestion**

You can do this in **Async** manner. You just fire the method `UpdateLastActivity()` and forget about the result. This way performance of your application won't get hampered.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: how well can i reply with this approach when the object is cached?

Comment: You can update the cache object once your DB is updated by the async thread. In other words your function `UpdateLastActivity()` will update the cache object once DB is updated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear how your system is constructed (cause it's actually a root point), but considering that you say that `#2` solution is better (from the call paths perspective), I would go for more reliable solution, naturally, unless it doesn't harm performance and not create frustration for my user.

If you're working on `DataBase` (it's not very clear from the question too), the common approach here is to use triggers bound to the table(s).

Comment: Hi tigran, yup i am using sql server 2005 Database and stored procedures. Could you elaborate more on how i can achieve this with triggers without headache( ooh yeah i've heard `Triggers trigger headcache's`)

Comment: There is nor headache on triggers, as on the content they execute. You can add a trigger for table(s) INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE (if needed) and update last activity date with the current time. The **good** is that you avoid roundtrip from client to server, the **bad** you should be very careful and pay attention on what you're doing as you're working with raw SQL, which is not easy to debug, in case when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that the methods should be kept separate. This is purely because the name of a method should reflect its purpose. Therefore placing the "update" functionality in a method that isn't named as such is not great practice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is rather a design pattern question. I don't know much about your architecture so code may change but my basic idea would be defining each activity as a class implementing the same interface such as below:

```
public interface IMemberActivity {
   void Execute(IMemberActivityLogger logger);
}
```